# Crud methods in service layer using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, design-patterns, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a small application using Spring and Spring Data JPA and I need to use the CrudRepository methods in the service layer, so I made 2 classes: GenericService and GenericServiceImpl. But I don't know if this is the right or even the best approach.

Here is an example:

POJO:

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String username;
}
```

DAO:

```
public interface UserDAO extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
  User findOneByUsername(String username);
}
```

Generic service

```
public interface GenericService<T, ID extends Serializable> {
  <S extends T> S save(S entity);
}
```

Service

```
public interface UserService extends GenericService<User, Long>  {
  User findOneByUsername(String username);
}
```

Generic service impl.

```
public class GenericServiceImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericService<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    private CrudRepository<T, ID> repository;

    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Service Impl.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<User, Long> implements UserService {

  @Autowired
  private UserDAO userDAO;

  @Override
  public User findOneByUsername(String username) {
    userDAO.findOneByUsername(username);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing all of that manual delegation instead of using the repository interfaces directly?

Comment: What do you mean by 'using the repository interfaces direclty'? I was trying to do something like this [Spring and Autowiring of Generic Types](http://www.jayway.com/2013/11/03/spring-and-autowiring-of-generic-types/)

Comment: I mean autowire your `CrudRepository` directly into the code that's manipulating the objects instead of having a separate service hierarchy that just replicates it.

Comment: It is ok to access the UserDAO from the controller? I don't really need the service layer I just did this because I thought it would be the best practice.

Comment: Yes, if your service tier isn't adding further logic. You'll want separation for larger projects when the service tier does more than just data access.

Comment: Is this really working? Was trying it but getting always a exception during the startup of my app: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository] found for dependency (Using JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository)

Comment: @chrylis what if half of the domains need business logic(service layer) and the other half not. I would definitely have service layer for business logic, but what is best for other domains. Using Repository directly from controller for **simplicity** vs generic service layer for **similar code structure**?

Comment: I am personally in favor of always adding a service layer between the Controller and the DAO. I don't see the point of the service interfaces though, I would just make a UserService class without an interface. Also, as mentioned by StephanM I don't think your GenericServiceImpl will actually work because it autowires a bean that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're providing your own impl that's may do custom things while still reusing the Derived queries from Spring JPA's CrudRepository. I've seen that a lot. :) We need to do that if we want to do our own computation before calling the Derived methods. After all, that computation may very well be part of a repository, so it doesn't make sense to put that logic in the service. But in your scenario, if there are no such custom computations, then this indirection isn't needed. As a commenter mentioned, you should directly use the UserDao interface. :)